# ¿Es posible en Android guardar en una variable una referencia a una Activity para usarla luego en un Intent?

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Tengo el siguiente código, que escucha los clicks ocurridos en los elementos de un `RecyclerView` para llamar a otra `Activity` según el item presionado.

```
public void onItemClick(MainItem item) {
    Intent i;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case 1:
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BreviarioActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 2:
            i = new Intent(this, MisaActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 3:
            i = new Intent(this, HomiliasActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;


        case 4:
            i = new Intent(this, SantosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 5:
            i = new Intent(this, LecturasActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 6:
            i = new Intent(this, ComentariosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 7:
            i = new Intent(this, CalendarioActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 8:
            i = new Intent(this, OracionesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 9:

            i = new Intent(this, MainMasActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
    }
}
```

Así como está el código funciona bien, pero pienso que en cada `case` podría ahorrarme estas dos líneas:

```
            i = new Intent(this, ...);
            startActivity(i);
```

Pero para ello debería guardar una referencia a cada cada `Activity` según los `case`, para luego hacer, fuera de los case algo así:

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, refActivityGuardada);
startActivity(i);
```

`refActivityGuardada` equivaldría a cada referencia a las diferentes `Activity` según cada  `case`.

Lo que no sé es cómo guardar en una variable esto: `BreviarioActivity.class, MisaActivity.class`, etc.

**¿Es posible guardarlo?, ¿Cómo?**

**¿Es conveniente hacerlo?**

> He visto respuestas que recomiendan usar `Reflection` para esto. Mi
>   duda mayor es si es posible guardar una `Activity` (que no es otra
>   cosa que una clase) como se guarda una variable cualquiera y si
>   valdría la pena hacerlo para ahorrar algunas líneas de código.
>
> O, planteado de otro modo: ¿es posible guardar una clase como se
>   guarda una cadena, un entero, un booleano? ¿cuál sería el precio de
>   hacerlo? ¿vale la pena? O sea, no quiero recurrir a procedimientos
>   oscuros por ahorrar unas cuantas líneas de código.
>
> O, ¿no es posible hacerlo?  ¿Por qué no es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi punto de vista NO recomiendo que guardes referencias de tus activitys

lo que te sugiero y se me ocurre en este momento es esto:

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        onItemClick(1);//pasa el item
    }

    public void onItemClick(int item) {
        switch (item) {
            case 1:
                starActivity(EditImageActivity.class);
                break;

            case 2:
                starActivity(MisaActivity.class);
                break;

            case 3:
                starActivity(HomiliasActivity.class);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void starActivity(Class<?> activity) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, activity);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Existen buenas y malas practicas hacerca de como escibir codigo, no sabria en donde encaja tu pregunta, pero si lo que quieres ahorar lineas de codigo, te recomiendo esto:
Para guardar en una variable tu activity.class deberías en cada 'case' asignarla a una variable, estoy agrega 2 líneas de código, ya que primero deberás crear antes del switch la variable y en cada case asignarle un valor para después al final del switch iniciar la activity, esto en un final son 4 líneas de código, la cual la puedes resumir a 1 por cada case de la siguiente forma

```
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ComentariosActivity.class));
```

Espero que se entienda, cualquier cosa responde a mi pregunta!